# Several nested sub ​​grids in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to put a subgrid when each row have child rows.

This is my view:

[image]

For example, if i press the + in COMERCIOS, some grid is opened and show two child rows..

I want to set a plus + when the row has one child or more.

I tried to use jqgrd Grid as Subgrid but it is not what i want.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't describe what you want exactly, but maybe treegrid is the way for you: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid. Please describe the scenario in more details.

Comment: This is what i need ! thnxs! @tpeczek

Comment: Happy to hear that, I provided answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use treegrid functionality of jqGrid. You can find samples and more informations here:

- [jqGrid Documentation - TreeGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid)
- [jqGrid and ASP.NET MVC - TreeGrid](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2009/12/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-treegrid.html) (A little bit old but in general still valid)
- [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) ('New in version 3.3'/'Tree Grid' and 'New in version 3.5'/'TreeGrid real world example'
- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)
- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC - Strongly typed helper](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)